# Using dependent fields without Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I was wondering if it was possible to make a "dependent" field in a web form without using Javascript ?

My code consists in this :

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

And when I select a value, another select is populated, via JQuery's $.post(), with data fetched from my database.

But how can I keep this if the browser has JS disabled, or do not support Javascript ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: He just said he wants to keep it if js is disabled. The short answer is you can't, page interaction like that requires js to be enabled.

Comment: AJAX requires JavaScript.

Comment: You can test test to see if JavaScript is enable and if not use a pure css dropdownlist

Comment: @beaumondo likely if JS is disabled the person will not use CSS3 compatible browser.

Comment: This can be done without javascript in the .NET world using `runat="server"` elements and `autopostback="true"` on the select, but as a user i'd rather have none of the page work than see something autopostback in 2013.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by pure CSS dropdownlist ?

Comment: I can't use .NET, since I do this in PHP, sorry :/

Comment: @jbabey the `autopostback` in asp.net property works via Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to trigger an event like this. You need to reload the document and pass your data through some server code. (PHP or something else)

Comment: Do you mean adding a submit button for my select field, which will submit part of my form and process it ?

I can do this, but it's kinda hard to make, I think, since I am using form validation (I am coding using CodeIgniter framework), and the rest of my form might not be validated

Comment: Yes, this would be my solution. Submit the value of your first select box by POST. Depending on the source of your data, you only need to rebuild the options of your select field by a loop. Its easier with static options for your second select box, of course.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I will try to code this way for future developments !

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the HTML5's specification of [option](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-option-element) and [select](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-select-element) elements, I would say it's impossible.